# Login form : (The password you entered was not valid)

Tags: php

i need help to solve this. i want to login but i encounter this error.

```
<?php

require_once 'includes/config.php';

$username = $password = "";

$username_err = $password_err = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

{

    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"])))

    {

        $username_err = 'Please enter username.';

    }

    else

    {

        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);

    }

    if(empty(trim($_POST['password'])))

    {

        $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';

    } 

    else

    {

        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    }

    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err))

    {

        $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM students WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql))

        {

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            $param_username = $username;

            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt))

            {

                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1)

                {                    

                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);

                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))

                    {

                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password))

                        {

                            session_start();

                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  

                            header("location: welcome.php");

                        } 

                        else

                        {

                            $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';

                        }

                    }

                } 

                else

                {

                    $username_err = 'No account found with that username.';

                }

            }

             else

             {

                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";

            }

        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    }

    mysqli_close($link);

}

?>
```

Comment: What does `password_verify()` do?

Comment: For debugging purposes, please show us the output of `var_dump()` for the variables `$password` and `$hashed_password` before you call the `password_verify()` function. Add the output of the function to your question, not in a comment.